# Webpart disappears after migrating site collection from sSP010 to SP2013

Tags: web-part, migration

I need to migrate several site collections from SP2010 to SP2013. After I migrated the sites to SP2013 farm and create a evaluation copy, the site customized layout are all lost. (It is expected since Microsoft said I need to re-create the masterpage and theme). However one of customized webparts also disappears. It is a natvigation menu webpart. This webpart will show buttons according to a list "menu items" under the site collection. The list have be migrated successfully but the webpart is not showing anywhere.

I have setup the migrated the same site collection in SP2010 mode. The menu webpart do exist. I can check its "webpartid" by view source in the browser.

May I know how can I import the webpart into the SP2013 enviroment again? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following things:

1. Specify the "SharePoint Product version=15.0" in your manifest file.
2. Upgrade the solutions using VS 2012

For reference use:

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/deploy-wsp-to-14-and-15-hives-in-sharepoint-2013.html

http://zimmergren.net/technical/upgrading-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions-to-sharepoint-2013